# CSS - Conditional for Exact Mobile Aspect Ratio

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari

I'm trying to have the mobile browser (iOS Safari) load a webpage with a different fullscreen exact-pixel-dimension image (`.bg` tag) based on the aspect ratio of the iOS device.

For some reason, every time, I try loading the page on an iPhone X (which has a rather long screen 2436x1125, so definitely greater than a 19/9 ratio in the third conditional below), it defaults to the middle option, i.e. the 16/9 option...

Each image is exact to the aspect ratio, so should fill up the screen completely, though for some reason currently the middle conditional (being for 16/9 and not 19/9) is cropping the sides on my long iPhone X. (right click/inspect to see the border)

[image: Image from Gyazo]

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%; margin:0;padding:0;
    width:100%;
}

.bg { 
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("640p.png");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;  width:100%;

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 1136/640) {
    .bg { 
    background-image: url("640p.png"); height: 100%;  width:100%;
    }
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) and (max-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
    .bg { 
    background-image: url("1080p.png"); height: 100%;  width:100%;
    }
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 19/9) {
    .bg { 
    background-image: url("1125p.png"); height: 100%;  width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<html><body>

<div class="bg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```